# Is there any good way to determine the "actual content width" of a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, screen-resolution

Here's what StackOverflow looks like on my (huge) work monitor:

[image: Screenshot of StackOverflow]

That is **a lot of white space** on either side of the site's actual content.

I get that this is how a very large percentage of websites are designed—so I'm not singling out SO here—but that's actually exactly why I'm asking this question. I'm thinking it'd be really nice if I had some reliable way (say, via JavaScript) of determining the "actual" width of a website, which I could then use to write a quick script that would auto expand any site I'm browsing to fill the available width on my monitor. As it is, I find it absurd that sometimes I still squint before reading tiny text before realizing/remembering to zoom in to take advantage of my enormous screen.

[image: Zoomed-in screenshot of StackOverflow]

Ahh... much better.

I *suspect* this is possible, at least to a reasonable degree via some heuristic, as my Android phone appears to do something a lot like this when I double-tap on the screen while browsing the web.

Comment: http://gmail.com does it too. You will notice it best of you have _multiple inboxes_ enabled. If you resize your window, you usually have to refresh the page for it to re-partition the interface

Answer (score 2):

This will do something sorta like that.  Though probably misses all kinds of edge cases.

```
// Assuming jQuery for simplicity
var drillIn = function(node) {
  var max = 0;
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var result = 0;

  $(node).children().each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.width() > max) {
      max = $this.width();
    }
  });

  if (0 < max && max < windowWidth) {
    return max;
  } else {
    $(node).children().each(function() {
      var childMax = drillIn(this);
      if (childMax > result) {
        result = childMax;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
};

drillIn(document.body);
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bdL5b/1/

On SO, I get `960` which is right.  Basically it drills into the DOM tree to find the widest node closest to the root which is not `0` or the window width.  Because usually, close to the root node there is a container node which holds the site content.  Usually.

Not sure you will get a 100% reliable solution though.  This is a tricky thing because there are a TON of ways to style websites.  I bet crazy stuff like horrible use of absolute positioning could be a serious thorn in your ass.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox, [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) is awesome. It will run Javascript that you write on any page (I have used it on Stack Overflow's site before).

Just use the browser's built-in "inspect element," to get the id of whatever you want to expand and do this:

```
document.getElementById("content").style.width = "100%";  // content is just an example
```

I think the class name of the middle boxes is `.container` so you could do this:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
{
    boxes[i].style.width = "100%";
}
```

As far as a heuristic for doing this arbitrarily, there's probably no good way to do it to all web pages in an unbiased way, *without significantly messing up the site's appearance*.

That being said, this or something similar might work *ok*:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    divs[i].style.minWidth = "90%";
}
```

Comment: Sure, if I know the ID of the "content" element. What I'm wondering, though, is if there's a *pretty good* heuristic to figure out *what* that element is... so that I can expand it reliably for any arbitrary website.

Comment: @DanTao Another option is to add `font-size: 2em;`, or some larger `em` value, to the `html` element's CSS using Javascript which will make pages bigger on most sites without drastically destroying the page's styling.

Answer (score 1):

Ha! I've got something close (though I'm also going to try [Alex's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751403/105570)):

The following relies on jQuery and is arguably inefficient (it inspects, I believe, every element in the DOM); but it doesn't take any time on my machine and at least works with SO:

```
(function($) {
  function text($element) {
    return $.trim($element.clone().children().remove().end().text());
  }

  function hasContent($element) {
    return $element.is(":visible") && text($element).length > 0;
  }

  function getExtremeEdges($elements) {
    var extremeLeft = null;
    var extremeRight = null;

    $.each($elements, function(i, el) {
      var $element = $(el);
      var offset = $element.offset();

      if (!extremeLeft || offset.left < extremeLeft) {
        extremeLeft = offset.left;
      }
      if (!extremeRight || (offset.left + $element.width()) > extremeRight) {
        extremeRight = offset.left + $element.width();
      }
    });

    return [extremeLeft, extremeRight];
  }

  var $elementsWithContent = $("*").filter(function(i, el) {
    return hasContent($(el));
  });

  var extremeEdges = getExtremeEdges($elementsWithContent);

  var width = extremeEdges[1] - extremeEdges[0];

  var desiredWidth = $(document).width() * 0.95;

  if (width < desiredWidth) {
    $("body").css("zoom", (desiredWidth / width));
  }

}(jQuery));
```

Minified (to use as a bookmarklet):

```
(function(a){function b(b){return a.trim(b.clone().children().remove().end().text())}function c(a){return a.is(":visible")&&b(a).length>0}function d(b){var c=null;var d=null;a.each(b,function(b,e){var f=a(e);var g=f.offset();if(!c||g.left<c){c=g.left}if(!d||g.left+f.width()>d){d=g.left+f.width()}});return[c,d]}var e=a("*").filter(function(b,d){return c(a(d))});var f=d(e);var g=f[1]-f[0];var h=a(document).width()*.95;if(g<h){a("body").css("zoom",h/g)}})(jQuery);
```

Time to dogfood this puppy for a while...

Comment: Ha, as soon as I posted this answer it stopped working on this page... which led me to the realization that (I think) the element containing the minified JavaScript is preventing it from working. This calls for some more digging...

Comment: your script requires jQuery to be already present, so fails on say http://bbc.co.uk . why not also check for and inject jquery into the page if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @bPratik: Yeah, that's not a bad idea; though I was really thinking I'd just rewrite it later without jQuery.

Comment: @bPratik The important part is how often will the method work regardless of the library dependency.

Comment: @DanTao - here's an interesting approach: by learning how http://www.selectorgadget.com/ does the element picker, you do the same. the first time the script loads, you simple point and click the  element that you need to expand. This completely takes the dodgy heuristics out. Enhancements could be a timer where if you don't pick one, the heuristic kicks in. Another addition would be an ability to persist this data!

Answer (score 0):

Not much progress but I'm putting what I tried up in case it inspires anyone else:

**Works much worse than you would think**

Make a bookmarklet that makes all children of body have 100% width.  Then, if you click the bookmarklet again, it makes all children of children of body have 100% width.  This way, the user can just click until the site becomes more pleasing to them :)

```
var levels = levels ? levels + 1 : 1;
$('body *:nth-child(' + levels + ')').css({ width: '100%' });
```

.

**First approach to try and figure out where the first meaningful content is**

Cool puzzle, I'm employing the awesomeness of jQuery.  So I'm approaching it by trying to find the first element which has more non-empty `.contents()` than `.children()` because contents also fetches text nodes.  Here's what I have so far.  It's close, but not quite right because it seems to be searching a bit too deep:

```
$('body *:visible').filter(function(){
    return moreNonEmptyContentThanChildren($(this));
}).first();


function moreNonEmptyContentThanChildren(el) {
    var contentCount = 0;
    var contents = el.contents();
    for (c = 0; c < contents.length; c++) {
        elc = contents[c];
        if (elc.nodeType != 3 || (elc.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(elc).text()) != '')) {
            contentCount ++;
        }
    }
    return contentCount != el.children().length;
}
```

Comment: When run on this site, they both return the same value.  I don't think this does what he wants.  Or at least not reliably.

Comment: @AlexWayne is right: if I call `$(document).width()` on the SO page, I get 1656. However what I'm asking for would probably be roughly equal to `$("#content").width()`, which gives me 960.

Comment: Oh I see.  So basically he'd want something like `$('#content').width()` but it would dynamically figure out what `'#content'` would be.  Ok, I'm pondering :)

Comment: @Milimetric there's the rub! Calculating width is easy.  Figuring what to get the width of is the whole damn tuna here.

Comment: Cool puzzle though.  I've made some progress and updated my answer.  I think it's promising though not quite right yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think each website will be too different to have a standard was of auto resizing their content. I belive CSS is the key, by using user defined style sheets. Or something like [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/help/stylish). See https://superuser.com/questions/128666/custom-per-site-stylesheet-extension-for-firefox

or https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/style-sheet-chooser-ii/

Comment: Sure, but how would I apply my own custom CSS to an arbitrary site? The only way I know is to use JavaScript.

Comment: @Dan Tao Ahh yeah I just reread our question and now understand you just want this for your own PC on all sites. Your not developing your own website. In which case you question should probably be posted on 'Super User' or 'Web Applications' instead of SO

Comment: I don't know, though; I am actually asking from a programming standpoint for ideas on how to accomplish this. Doesn't that belong here?

Comment: @Daveo regardless of the goal, this is an interesting programming question that could have a real world non-personal use potentially.

Comment: You can use your own css on every site you visit, but that doesn't even begin to solve the problem of 'which element do i set width:100% to'...

Comment: @Vatev agreed but I do not think setting width(s):100% will make the site look correct either

Comment: @Daveo yes, it probably won't. The point is the problem is not 'what to do with the element', but 'which element'.